# Mono GTK# - PropertyNotifyEvent of window or widget

Tags: events, event-handling, mono, gtk#

I want to be able to react if a property of a given window or widget has been changed and found the `Gtk.Widget.PropertyNotifyEvent` event. The (mono) documentation says that it will be fired if any property has been changed. So I've tried to make use of it but my event handler method is never invoked:

```
protected void DoSomething()
{
    Gtk.Window __Window = new Gtk.Window(Gtk.WindowType.Toplevel);
    Gtk.Button __Button = new Gtk.Button();
    __Window.Add(__Button);
    __Button.PropertyNotifyEvent += this.ButtonPropertyChangedEventHandler;

    ... // Show the window

    __Button.Label = Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString("This is a test button");
}

protected void ButtonPropertyChangedEventHandler(object o, PropertyNotifyEventArgs e)
{
    // Handle the event
}
```

Do I miss something? Or did I understand something very basic wrong? Or is there another approach to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 1):

Property change notifications need to be explicitly enabled by setting the `GDK_PROPERTY_CHANGE_MASK` flag, as explained here:

https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget-property-notify-event

In Gtk# you just need to add the following line to your code:

__Button.Events |= Gdk.EventMask.PropertyChangeMask;

And the handler assigned to the `PropertyNotifyEvent` event will start to receive property change notifications. Gtk# enables *some* events implicitly but all others should be enabled from user code or from the stetic designer.